# Search friendly urls in Joomla 1.5 aren't updated in the site menu

Tags: iis, joomla, iis-7.5, joomla1.5, joomla-sef-urls

I'm working in a website developed in joomla 1.5 (I didn't created this site).

When I activate search friendly urls, almost urls of the menu are the same, only two different urls appears:

```
domain.com/index.php/home/
domain.com/index.php/history/
```

And these urls links with incorrect pages:

```
domain.com/index.php/history/
```

links to Contact page for example.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was easier than I thought. All the alias field were the same in the menu elements. When I changed the alias, the urls worked fine.